# Is a relational database just a $ \geq 2$-dimensional array?

Tags: data-structures

In terms of comparing data structures, is a relational database just a >1 dimensional array?  I'm just asking because I don't know much about databases, but I know a bit about data structures.

I am trying to make this clear in my mind.

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't. A data structure can be described in two ways:

1. How does it store the data.
2. Which operations are supported, their performance (usually given as asymptotic time- and/or space-complexity), and what laws do they obey.

Obviously, a database doesn't store all its data as a single array.

Arrays support, as basic operations, retrieving an element by index and storing an element under an index. Operations required for databases are (to a first approximation) given by [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra): selection, projection, union, difference, and join (or product).

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you could say that a database can be represented as a huge array. The benefit of a DB, however, is the ability to represent this huge array very succinctly.

More theoretically, the benefit of a DB can be compared to the topological fact that cylinder sets can be represented succinctly, as opposed to more complex subsets. Essentially, a DB is a representation of a cylinder set as a multiplication of its respective dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

In database literature this idea is widely known as [universal relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_relation_assumption).

Answer (score 0):

There is some basic similarity between relational DB and large array (table~multidimensional array).

Relational DB is based on [**relational algebra**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) which makes it powerful. By using relational operators, information could be retrieved, updated, inserted, deleted etc... in DB efficiently.

Considering array as a simple data structure, it only supports **read/write operators** in constant time $O(1)$. while in relational db you can write lots of complex queries using relational algebra.